# Using :after pseudo class to target child several divs below some other div

Tags: css

Say I have this structure

```
<div class="someclass">
   <div class = "someotherclass completed">
       <div class = "title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to display some icon after the Title if class `completed` is present in the div shown in my structure above.

I have tried

```css
.someclass .someotherclass.completed .title:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f058";
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
   <div class = "someotherclass completed">
       <div class = "title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But that does not result in the pseudo class being applied. Perhaps I am not understanding some fundamental aspect of pseudo selectors?

### Edit

I think something else in the CSS is interfering. I can only select that element with class "title" if I directly select it. `.title:after` works, but selecting via preceding classes, etc just doesn't work, so I need to figure out other way. Someone should write an app that lets you paste HTML, then outputs a CSS selector that works for a chosen element or class in the HTML!

### Solution

So the problem was that I overlooked the structure. The structure is actually

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class = "someotherclass completed"></div>
    <div class = "title">Title</div>
</div>
```

So there was icon being placed using before: pseudo class on `someotherclass`.

I now have it working as

```
.someclass div.someotherclass.completed + div.title:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f058";
}
```

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] that illustrates your issue. The code currently shown does not, https://jsfiddle.net/ew7kycg5/ (it does of course not render then font without that getting explicitly embedded, but at least the extra character shows up after the word Title.)

Comment: your code works fine if we consider the fact that you are correctly importing the font awesome CSS

Answer (score -2):

```css
.someotherclass{
  position:relative;
}

.someclass .someotherclass.completed .title:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f058";
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
** To use pseudo you need to use position relative for parent and absolute for child div.

<div class="someclass">
   <div class = "someotherclass completed">
       <div class = "title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

i think there is some mismtach in assigned font-family check it with 'font-family: FontAwesome'. Below code will fix this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.someclass .someotherclass.completed .title:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f058";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="someclass">
   <div class = "someotherclass completed">
       <div class = "title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is an another approach in fixing this issue as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
 i {
 font-family:'FontAwesome'}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="someclass">
   <div class = "someotherclass completed">
       <div class="title">Title<i class="fa-check-circle"></i></div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I had incorrectly assessed the layout and now things are working fine. Wow, this sort of work requires insane attention to detail!